# Android WebView embedded media content

Tags: android, webview

I have a `WebView` that needs to display HTML content provided by the back-end server. The content has different embedded Media types, such as: Instagram, Twitter, Animated GIFs, Facebook posts, YouTube, Vimeo videos.

Problem: I want the content to be contained inside the webview, so that it does not scroll horizontally. If I fix this, then the YouTube videos no longer work (blank placeholder appears, and nothing happens when clicking on it). Here is the code: (messy, I know):

```
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv_content);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);        
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());             
    mWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);//hopefully load GIFs faster
    mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);//hopefully load GIFs faster

    /** The line with the issue:
     * Upside: prevents horizontal scrolling, the content wraps;
     * Downside: YouTube videos no longer work. Blank placeholder appears
     */    
    mWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
```

I don't know what to do, to fix both the issue with the content wrapping, AND the issue with the Embedded YouTube videos.

This is the xml, if it helps:

```
             <WebView
                android:id="@+id/wv_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/generic_margin"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Medium"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/generic_text_size"
                tools:text="main title lorem ipsum dolore Typobli" />
```

Any suggestions are more than welcome.

Answer (score 2):

try to set

```
mWebView.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, but the `YouTube embedded` videos still don't work - just a blank placeholder, still.

Comment: I don't know why excatly causes your problem but you can try with removing layoutAlgorithm.

Comment: If I remove `LayoutAlgorithm` then I have another problem: `YouTube` videos WILL work, but the content will bleed - causing the view to scroll horizontally, which is what I don't want, either.

Comment: When your activity starts calculate screen width and set it to your html head manually which you load in webview.

Comment: Yes, unfortunatelly, this will be the only solution.

Comment: I haven't tried what you are trying to do but i solved my problem with manually setting screen witdth to html head. i hope it'll work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed as suggested by [savepopulation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1559852/savepopulation) below:

1). Created an HTML template, with the following `style` rule:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body, img, iframe, div {
    width: {{max_width}}px !important;
    }
</style>
<div>
        {{content_body}}
</div>
```

2). Read template from `assets` folder and replace placeholder:

```
template.replaceFirst("\\{\\{content_body\\}\\}", htmlContent).replaceFirst("\\{\\{max_width\\}\\}", String.valueOf(320));//put your computed value here
```

3). Load stuff into webview:

```
//veryVeryVery important for playing the videos and displaying embedded instagram photos
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(mBaseUrl, template, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```